# Angular filter ng-repeat subarray by checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of objects (users) with subarrays

```
[{
  name:'username',
  offer: [1,5,123,12]
},
{
  name:'username2',
  offer: [1,3,13,212]
}]
```

and i have a list of checkboxes (500 elements, grouped in accordion list)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in offers">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" 
            ng-model="search.offer[item.id]" 
            ng-true-value="{{item.id}}" 
            ng-false-value="undefined" /> 
        {{item.name}} </label>
</div>
```

Now, what Im trying to do is to show only users with checked properties. This is ng-repeat part with offerFilter

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter: search | offerFilter">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="media/sezon_lowerq.jpg" alt="image">
                    <div class="caption" style="height:7em">
                        <strong ng-if="profile.name">{{ profile.name }}</strong>
                        <span ng-if="profile.lastname">{{ profile.firstname }} {{ profile.lastname }}</span>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#/profile/{{ profile.id }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

offerFilter looks like this

```
var myFilters = angular.module('myFilters', []);

myFilters.filter('offerFilter', function() {
    return function(items) {

        var results = [];
        if (items) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if(items[i].offer.length>0 && items[i].offer!=0){
                    for (var j = 0; j < items[i].offer.length;j++){
                        var value = items[i].offer[j];

                        if (results.indexOf(value) == -1) {
                            results.push(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return results;
        } else {
          return 'Doh!';
        }
   }
})
```

Problem is, that when i check even one checkbox (for example with value="1"), everything hides.

Comment: What is the question? Where is the code you have tried to resolve this with?

Answer (score 0):

Ive found the solution using ng-change and ng-show directives

```
$scope.offertest = function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.profiles,function(profile,$index){
            profile.offertest = true;   
        });

        angular.forEach($scope.searchoffer,function(item,key){
            if(item){
                var keepGoing = true;
                angular.forEach($scope.profiles,function(profile,$index){
                    if(keepGoing){
                        if(profile.offer.length>0 && profile.offer!=0){ 
                            if(profile.offer.indexOf(item)==-1){
                                profile.offertest = false;  
                                keepGoing = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            profile.offertest = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                delete $scope.searchoffer[key];
            }
        });
    }
```

The checkboxes has now ng-change directive. search.offer is now searchoffer.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    ng-model="searchoffer[item.id]" 
    ng-change="offertest()"
    ng-true-value="{{item.id}}" 
    ng-false-value="0" /> 
    {{offer.name}} </label>
```

And users list

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter: search"` ng-show="profile.offertest">..</div>
```

it works, but probably there is better solution...